# Division won't stay hidden after returning to page javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problem with keeping division persistently hidden. My javascript function is working, it changes division style display, but after I save changes and later return on page, division is visible even if I chose option in select which should keep division hidden

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="cancelation" class="dropdown" id="dropdownRefundOption">
    <option value="refundable">Refundable</option>
    <option value="non-refundable">Non-Refundable</option>
</select>
<div class="row cancelationDaysRow" id="divisionRefundOption"> <span class="no-margin-left">Up to</span>
    <div class="input-holder">
        <input name="cancelationDays" id="cancelation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancelation days') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('30') ?>" value="30" class="input-text input-text_inner" type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="3" />
    </div> <span>days before the starting date of this tour</span>
</div>
```

Here is my JS script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

var dropdownRefOpt = document.getElementById("dropdownRefundOption");
var divRefOpt = document.getElementById("divisionRefundOption");

dropdownRefOpt.onchange = function () {
    if (dropdownRefOpt.value == "non-refundable") divRefOpt.style.display = 'none';
    else divRefOpt.style.display = 'block';
};

</script>
```

Comment: _" after I save changes"_ How do you save the changes?

Comment: There is a "save change" button on the page. It's a Magento application, "save change" button is already implemented and works for every other field except this

Comment: How is the value set on page load of the dropdown? If I had to guess, the initial setting of the field does not trigger the onchange when the page loads.

Comment: Well the actual problem here is when I choose "Non-refundable" option from the dropdown and save changes, after I return to page it still shows division, even if it shouldn't. Yes, your guess is right! Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: Without know how you are setting that value its hard to say. I would update question with more info on where and how that value is set when the page loads.

Comment: Well that is the problem, because it's a Magento app and I didn't write backend part of it, so I cannot find where and how is set when the page loads. But I'm trying to find a solution with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

So either the serverside needs to set up the correct state when the page loads, you you need to trigger code that sets the elements state when the page is running.

So either trigger the onchange event after you set it.

```
dropdownRefOpt.onchange = function(){ /* your code here */ };
dropdownRefOpt.onchange();
```

or move the code to a method and call it.

```
function yourCode () { /* your code here */ }
dropdownRefOpt.onchange = yourCode;
yourCode();
```

Comment: It's not working. I suppose server side is the problem then?

Comment: What is not working exactly? Did the onchange get triggered?  Did you debug to make sure it is going into the correct step and the correct values are there?

Comment: The actual problem here is when I choose "Non-refundable" option from the dropdown and save changes, after I return to page it still shows division, even if it shouldn't. So on loading the page it shows division, even though "Non-refundable" option is chosen in select.

Comment: Yes when the page is loading you need to set the state of division correctly upon setting value of dropdown or after setting the value of dropdown and attaching onchange, manually trigger the change event or call the function attached to the change event.

Comment: @dmikic So calling onchange did not fire and set the state correctly?

Comment: @epascarello No, it didn't.

Comment: @epascarello Do you have any ideas?